# Python Flask application cannot be accessed by remote computers in network

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I ran a simple flask web application on python on my localhost.

The web application is running on 127.0.0.1:8000. But I cannot access it from a remote machine in my network using myHostComputerIPaddress:8000.

My host is a windows machine. Please advise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `app.run()` function must be `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` in order to give access other devices on same network.